# spotbugs failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: java, maven, spotbugs

I'm getting an error while running mvn clean install. Locally, I have jdk 11 installed. The project is also using jdk 11.
[image: Here is the error I get. On most threads on internet I saw it only on JDK 17+.]

I am using a Macbook pro with an M1 chip.

Comment: https://openjdk.org/jeps/411

Comment: shouldn't be on jdk 11 afaik

Comment: What is the output of `mvn -v`. Also, please replace the screenshot with actual text. The error suggests you're using Java 12 or higher, with `-Djava.security.manager=disallow` specified, or with Java 18 where that behaviour has become the default.

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade your spotbugs-maven-plugin to most recent version

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Simply add JAVA_HOME to your system environment variables and point it to your jdk-11 folder e.g C:\Users\Program Files\Java\jdk-11. This resolved it for me